# Laravel: Apply validation rule only if the another one passed

Tags: php, validation, laravel

In my Laravel 5.2 app, I have the following validation rules to check a field:

```
$rules = array(
    'file' => 'mimes:jpg,png,pdf,doc,docx',
    'file' => 'validate_file'
);
```

Now, the `validate_file` is a custom validation rule. I want to run it only **only if** the first `mimes` validation passes.

I know I could simply validate/redirect with errors - in two batches, first the `mimes`, then the `validate_file`, but it seems like an overkill.

Any way I can do it the smart way in Laravel 5.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "bail" attribute. It will stop validation after first failure.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'title' => 'bail|mimes:jpg,png,pdf,doc,docx|validate_file',
]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#validation-quickstart search for "bail"

Comment: Nice. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: What should be pointed out, though, is that `bail` works only on the level of a single value, in this case only for the `title` field. If there are other fields validated afterwards, their validation will still take place.

Comment: This is not really the correct answer to the question, what happens if field is different for second validation?

Comment: @PHPLover What do you mean with that?