# Laravel Validation proceed to next validation only if above validation passed

Tags: php, laravel, validation

The question is very similiar to: [Laravel: Apply validation rule only if the another one passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37408870/laravel-apply-validation-rule-only-if-the-another-one-passed), however the answer to that question is wrong.

```
$rules = array(
    'file' => 'mimes:jpg,png,pdf,doc,docx',
    'anotherFile' => 'validate_file'
);
```

I would like to run `anotherFile` validation only if `file` validation passes.

Is this possible with Laravel?

Comment: What I actually need is to recieve only 1 error, only the first error.

Comment: Did you mean to use something like `required_if:file` as referenced here https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/11986?

Comment: @OmisakhOluwatobi yes

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do this? When the first one fails it doesn't matter if the rest succeeds or not: the validation will fail anyways.

If you only want do do something with the one error you can just get that error with:

```
$errors->first('file')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `bail` to stop at the moment when it fails.

```
$rules = array(
    'file' => 'bail|mimes:jpg,png,pdf,doc,docx',
    'anotherFile' => 'validate_file'
);
```